# How to sort paginated logs by @timestamp with Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

My goal is to sort millions of logs by timestamp that I receive out of Elasticsearch.

Example logs:

```
{"realIp": "192.168.0.2", "@timestamp": "2020-12-06T02:00:09.000Z"}
{"realIp": "192.168.0.2", "@timestamp": "2020-12-06T02:01:09.000Z"}
{"realIp": "192.168.0.2", "@timestamp": "2020-12-06T02:02:09.000Z"}
{"realIp": "192.168.0.2", "@timestamp": "2020-12-06T02:04:09.000Z"}
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to get all the logs sorted out of Elastic. It seems like I have to do it by myself.

Approaches I have tried to get the data sorted out of elastic:

```
es = Search(index="somelogs-*").using(client).params(preserve_order=True)
for hit in es.scan():
    print(hit['@timestamp'])
```

Another approach:

```
notifications = (es
    .query("range", **{
        "@timestamp": {
            'gte': 'now-48h',
            'lt' : 'now'
        }
    })
    .sort("@timestamp")
    .scan()
)
```

So I am looking for a way to sort these logs by myself or directly through Elasticsearch. Currently, I am saving all the data in a local 'logs.json' and it seems to me I have to iter over and sort it by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Gino Mempin. It works!

But I also figured out, that a simple change does the same job.

by adding `.params(preserve_order=True)` elasticsearch will sort all the data.

```
es = Search(index="somelog-*").using(client)
notifications = (es
    .query("range", **{
        "@timestamp": {
            'gte': 'now-48h',
            'lt' : 'now'
        }
    })
    .sort("@timestamp")
    .params(preserve_order=True)
    .scan()
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely let Elasticsearch do the sorting, then return the data to you already sorted.

The problem is that you are using [`.scan()`](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#pagination). It uses Elasticsearch's scan/scroll API, which unfortunately only applies the sorting params on each page/slice, not the entire search result. This is noted in the [elasticsearch-dsl docs on Pagination](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#pagination):

> #### Pagination
>
> ...
> If you want to access all the documents matched by your query you can
> use the scan method which uses the scan/scroll elasticsearch API:
>
> ```
> for hit in s.scan():
>     print(hit.title)
> ```
>
> **Note that in this case the results won’t be sorted.**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Using pagination is definitely an option especially when you have a "*millions of logs*" as you said. There is a [`search_after` pagination API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after):

> #### Search after
>
> You can use the `search_after` parameter to retrieve the next page of
> hits using a set of [sort values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html) from the previous page.
> ...
> To get the first page of results, submit a search request with a `sort`
> argument.
> ...
> The search response includes an array of `sort` values for
> each hit.
> ...
> To get the next page of results, rerun the previous search using the last hit’s `sort` values as the `search_after` argument. ... The search’s `query` and `sort` arguments must remain unchanged. If provided, the `from` argument must be `0` (default) or `-1`.
> ...
> You can repeat this process to get additional pages of results.

<sub>(omitted the raw JSON requests since I'll show a sample in Python below)</sub>

Here's a sample how to do it with [elasticsearch-dsl for Python](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Note that I'm limiting the `fields` and the number of results to make it easier to test. The important parts here are the `sort` and the `extra(search_after=)`.

```py
search = Search(using=client, index='some-index')

# The main query
search = search.extra(size=100)
search = search.query('range', **{'@timestamp': {'gte': '2020-12-29T09:00', 'lt': '2020-12-29T09:59'}})
search = search.source(fields=('@timestamp', ))
search = search.sort({
    '@timestamp': {
        'order': 'desc'
    },
})

# Store all the results (it would be better to be wrap all this in a generator to be performant)
hits = []

# Get the 1st page
results = search.execute()
hits.extend(results.hits)
total = results.hits.total
print(f'Expecting {total}')

# Get the next pages
# Real use-case condition should be "until total" or "until no more results.hits"
while len(hits) < 1000:  
    print(f'Now have {len(hits)}')
    last_hit_sort_id = hits[-1].meta.sort[0]
    search = search.extra(search_after=[last_hit_sort_id])
    results = search.execute()
    hits.extend(results.hits)

with open('results.txt', 'w') as out:
    for hit in hits:
        out.write(f'{hit["@timestamp"]}\n')
```

That would lead to an *already sorted* data:

```
# 1st 10 lines
2020-12-29T09:58:57.749Z
2020-12-29T09:58:55.736Z
2020-12-29T09:58:53.627Z
2020-12-29T09:58:52.738Z
2020-12-29T09:58:47.221Z
2020-12-29T09:58:45.676Z
2020-12-29T09:58:44.523Z
2020-12-29T09:58:43.541Z
2020-12-29T09:58:40.116Z
2020-12-29T09:58:38.206Z
...
# 250-260
2020-12-29T09:50:31.117Z
2020-12-29T09:50:27.754Z
2020-12-29T09:50:25.738Z
2020-12-29T09:50:23.601Z
2020-12-29T09:50:17.736Z
2020-12-29T09:50:15.753Z
2020-12-29T09:50:14.491Z
2020-12-29T09:50:13.555Z
2020-12-29T09:50:07.721Z
2020-12-29T09:50:05.744Z
2020-12-29T09:50:03.630Z 
...
# 675-685
2020-12-29T09:43:30.609Z
2020-12-29T09:43:30.608Z
2020-12-29T09:43:30.602Z
2020-12-29T09:43:30.570Z
2020-12-29T09:43:30.568Z
2020-12-29T09:43:30.529Z
2020-12-29T09:43:30.475Z
2020-12-29T09:43:30.474Z
2020-12-29T09:43:30.468Z
2020-12-29T09:43:30.418Z
2020-12-29T09:43:30.417Z
...
# 840-850
2020-12-29T09:43:27.953Z
2020-12-29T09:43:27.929Z
2020-12-29T09:43:27.927Z
2020-12-29T09:43:27.920Z
2020-12-29T09:43:27.897Z
2020-12-29T09:43:27.895Z
2020-12-29T09:43:27.886Z
2020-12-29T09:43:27.861Z
2020-12-29T09:43:27.860Z
2020-12-29T09:43:27.853Z
2020-12-29T09:43:27.828Z
...
# Last 3
2020-12-29T09:43:25.878Z
2020-12-29T09:43:25.876Z
2020-12-29T09:43:25.869Z
```

There are some considerations on using [`search_after`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) as discussed in the API docs:

- Use a [Point In Time or PIT parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html)

  - > If a refresh occurs between these requests, the order of your results may change, causing inconsistent results across pages. To prevent this, you can create a [point in time (PIT)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html) to preserve the current index state over your searches.
  - You need to first make a POST request to get a PIT ID
  - Then add an `extra` `'pit': {'id':xxxx, 'keep_alive':5m}` parameter to every request
  - Make sure to use the PIT ID from the last response
- Use a tiebreaker

  - > We recommend you include a tiebreaker field in your sort. This tiebreaker field should contain a unique value for each document. If you don’t include a tiebreaker field, your paged results could miss or duplicate hits.
  - This would depend on your Document schema

    ```
    # Add some ID as a tiebreaker to the `sort` call
    search = search.sort(
        {'@timestamp': {
            'order': 'desc'
        }},
        {'some.id': {
            'order': 'desc'
        }}
    )

    # Include both the sort ID and the some.ID in `search_after`
    last_hit_sort_id, last_hit_route_id = hits[-1].meta.sort
    search = search.extra(search_after=[last_hit_sort_id, last_hit_route_id])
    ```